# Move Windows 7 user-directory to D:\user

Tags: windows-7

My user-directory is located at C:\Users\user. Is there any way to move it to a different hard-disk? I'm having some trouble with free disk-space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For normal user accounts: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/win7-how-do-i-move-user-folder-to-a-different/565f16a5-e5ed-43c9-8422-4f56aebb296e

For group policy: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx

Comment: Thanks for these links... however the recommended procedure is much too complex. Seriously... this is mad. I just want to move my homes.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your AppData folder is absolutely ginormous, you could probably get away with just relocating your Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Videos, etc. folders.  There's a "Location" tab in the properties for each folder.  When you change it and click Apply (or Ok), Windows will ask if you want to create the folder if it doesn't exist, and then ask you if you want it to move all your data to the new folder.