# Moving User Folder from C drive to D drive

Tags: windows

In every windows OS, the User Profiles will be automatically created on the C: drive. We would like to migrate the user profile to the D: drive because then the data it will be saved in outr backup process.

How can I migrate the user directory from the C drive to the D drive?

Will this works if I make an image and re-image on different machine?

Details
Platform : Windwow 7Enterprise
Machine : DELL and Toshiba

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving users folder on Windows Vista/Seven to another partition](http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition), [Move Windows 7 user-directory to D:\user](http://superuser.com/questions/288878/move-windows-7-user-directory-to-d-user) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this for a Win7 installation:

1. Copy the C:\users\Username user dir to D:\users\Username
2. Go through the registry and changing all C:\Users\UserName... to
   D:\Users\UserName...
3. Reboot.

[The usual cautions apply: make disk/registry backups first]

Answer (score 0):

Move the user folder to D: and then symlink it

```
mklink /J C:\Users D:\Users
```

You might need to use a bootcd/usb stick to fully move the user folder