# Can I use Windows 7 and 8 on the same partition to share users' files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, user-accounts

I was wondering if it were at all possible to completely wipe my laptop's hard drive and then create two partitions, one at the beginning (after the system partition) with 200GB, and the rest of the space (approximately 100GB).

What I wanted to do is in that first 200GB partition, which I would partition as an NTFS drive, install both Windows 7 and 8 which could both share the users' files. The rest could be split.

Or, if possible, have the two OS's on separate partitions but sharing the same user accounts with all the subfolders, such as the documents and the downloads etc.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend installing both OSes on the same partition. Regarding moving the Users folder, MS doesn't recommend this, but take a look at [Move Windows 7 user-directory to D:\user](http://superuser.com/questions/288878/move-windows-7-user-directory-to-d-user) and similar questions. There are also lots of guides on the net about how to do this using dir junctions. An easier option might be to move your Documents etc. folders (via right-click / Properties) rather than the entire Users folder itself.

Comment: @jjhacker810 - Any version of Windows would honor the requests of a previous version of Windows.  This means a user profile on Windows 7 would be unable to access the user profile of a user on Windows 8 which is what you want.  What would be easier is to make a single partition where all the data is stored outside of the user profile. Of course installing two operating systems on the same partition is not possible also.

Answer (score 0):

No is not possible. i think maybe you can install windows 7 and 8 on different partions and change windows 7 path of user folder to the one of window 8 (not viceversa because windows 8 add some new folder and permision for metro) --> this is only an idea i dont know if ti works

you can use for this a junction link (search google)